# Grails & Spring Security & Facebook & Oauth2 - Restfull server

Tags: facebook, rest, grails, spring-security, oauth-2.0

What would be the actual solution to build a server with Grails and Spring Security that meets the following requirements :

- Access to the server would be restfull, so only by third party clients (mobile,...)
- The authentication would use the oauth2 facebook services and the client would use a facebook SDK to provide a token to the server
- The authentication would be on per request basis so the token would be passed on the request as GET parameter (not POST as the Rest API uses it)
- No need to access Facebook user's information, only authentication

I tried Spring Security Facebook but the Json filter only returns user details so no per request or per session authentication.

I noticed Spring Security Oauth2 Provider but to me it's a provider and not a consumer that could plug into another provider like Facebook so no clue on how to use it.

Spring Social doesn't seem to meet my requirements.

As a result of this search for information, I intend to write a plugin to create a Restfull server connected to facebook.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [OAuth Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/oauth) to your rescue. It acts as a client to all the providers to get the access token. Follow the docs you will get what you need. BTW were you talking about the [Spring Security OAuth plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-oauth) which is wrapper over oauth plugin by spring security plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a security filter on the top of all your requests, and then if the request contains an auth header for the API you respond with as a restful API, otherwise you redirect your users to the login page, handled by the oauth authentication service, where you let the users login with the oath method (facebook, mozilla persona or whatever you like)